# Php Dynamic Sitemap After 50K Url

Tags: php

Hello I Need some help with dynamic sitemap using PHP
This is my code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/xml; charset="ISO-8859-1"', true);
$dataAll1 = scandir('cache-data');
unset($dataAll1[0]);
unset($dataAll1[1]);
unset($dataAll1[2]);
$sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <urlset xmlns="'.PROTOCOL.'://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

$sitemap .= '<url>
                        <loc>' . SITE_HOST . '</loc>
                        <priority>1.0</priority>
                     </url>';

foreach($dataAll1 as $val){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('cache-data/'.$val),1);
    if($val=='index.php'){
        continue;
    }
    $sitemap .= '<url>
                   <loc>'.SITE_HOST . '/job-detail/' . $data['jk'].'jktk'.$data['tk'] . '-' . $service->slugify($data['title']).'</loc>
                        <priority>0.9</priority>
                        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
                     </url>';
}

$sitemap.='</urlset>';
echo $sitemap;
```

this code success build sitemap file but after 50K this code wont make new file sitemap, so how to make this code want make new file sitemap after 50K Url?

I really appreciate any help

Comment: I would recommend to switch from a PHP that serves the sitemap when it's called, to a cronjob that generates static XMLs. Basically instead of `echo $sitemap` you save that in an xml file with `fwrite`. Then you need to keep a counter in your `foreach` loop and when it reached 50k, you need to write the sitemap file with an increased number. E.g. sitemap1.xml, sitemap2.xml. Finally you write a [sitemapindex file](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index) that points to the sitemaps you generated

Comment: @AndreaOlivato - You should write that up as an answer and maybe show an example of a sitemapindex file.

Comment: could you show me how the correct code?

Comment: @M.Eriksson thanks for the suggestion. Just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to switch from a web page that serves the sitemap when it's called, to a script that generates static XMLs and that you can optionally call via `crontab`.

### Step 1: Define directory where sitemaps are saved

This will be used to write one static `xml` file for each sitemap, plus the sitemap index. The directory needs to be writable from the user running the script and accessible via web.

```
define('PATH_TO_SITEMAP', __DIR__.'/www/');
```

### Step 2: Define the public URL where the sitemaps will be reachable

This is the Web URL of the folder you defined above.

```
define('HTTP_TO_SITEMAP', 'https://yourwebsite.com/');
```

### Step 3: Write sitemaps to file

Instead of `echo` the Sitemap, write it to static xml files in the folder defined above.

Furthermore keep a counter (`$count_urls` in my example below) for the number of URLs and when it reaches 50k reset the counter, close the sitemap and open a new one.

Also, keep a counter of how many sitemaps you're creating (`$count_sitemaps` in my example below).

Here's a working example that keeps your structure but writes the multiple files. It's not ideal, you should use a class/method or a function to write the sitemaps and avoid repeated code, but I thought this would be easier to understand as it keeps the same approach you had in your code.

```
$h = fopen(PATH_TO_SITEMAP.'sitemap_'.$count_sitemaps.'.xml', 'w+');
fwrite($h, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="'.PROTOCOL.'://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>'.SITE_HOST.'</loc>
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
');

$count_urls = 0;
foreach ($dataAll1 as $val) {
    $count_urls++;
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('cache-data/'.$val), 1);
    if ($val == 'index.php') {
        continue;
    }
    // When you reach 50k, close the sitemap, increase the counter and open a new sitemap
    if ($count_urls >= 50000) {
        fwrite($h, '</urlset>');
        fclose($h);
        $count_sitemaps++;
        $h = fopen(PATH_TO_SITEMAP.'sitemap_'.$count_sitemaps.'.xml', 'w+');
        fwrite($h, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="'.PROTOCOL.'://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">');
        $count_urls = 0;
    }
    fwrite($h, '
        <url>
            <loc>'.SITE_HOST.'/job-detail/'.$data['jk'].'jktk'.$data['tk'].'-'.$service->slugify($data['title']).'</loc>
            <priority>0.9</priority>
            <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        </url>
    ');
}

// Important! Close the final sitemap and save it.
fwrite($h, '</urlset>');
fclose($h);
```

### Step 4: Write SitemapIndex

Finally you write a [sitemapindex](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index) file that points to all the sitemaps you generated using the same `$count_sitemaps` counter.

```
// Build the SitemapIndex
$h = fopen(PATH_TO_SITEMAP.'sitemap.xml', 'w+');
fwrite($h, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">');
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count_sitemaps; $i++) {
    fwrite($h, '
    <sitemap>
        <loc>'.HTTP_TO_SITEMAP.'sitemap_'.$i.'.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>'.date('c').'</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    ');
}
fwrite($h, '
</sitemapindex>');
fclose($h);
```

### Step 5 (optional): ping Google

```
file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap='.urlencode(HTTP_TO_SITEMAP.'sitemap.xml'));
```

### Conclusions

As mentioned this approach is a bit messy and doesn't follow best practices on code re-use, but it should be quite clear on how to loop, store multiple sitemaps and finally build the sitemapindex file.

For a better approach, I suggest you to look at this [open source Sitemap class](https://github.com/andreaolivato/Sitemap).

Answer (score 0):

You should start the array generated from the scandir with the 50001, but it would be better to split it into several scripts with a crontab, so you don't exhaust the server with excessive runtime; otherwise, increase the runtime of PHP scripts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).